# Replacing atmega8 with atmega328(arduino)

Tags: arduino, atmega, atmel

I was supplied with an arduino board in a workshop(which is a very old version board) similar to : 
[image] 
the board comes with atmega8 as a micro controller ..
I wanted to increase the performance and memory of my micro controller, so I purchased an atmega328 IC from ebay

[Atmega328 IC Arduino Duemilanove bootloader](http://www.ebay.in/itm/Atmega328-IC-Arduino-Duemilanove-bootloader-WDT-/140669233702)

After replacing the IC with atmega328, I changed the settings in my arduino IDE to atmega32 duemilanove board ..

When I supplied power to my arduino board, I noticed that the LED on pin13 is keeps on blinking continuosly(Though I pressed reset button many times)

Here's a little [**video**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11jbMcm8SyU) I made after replacing the IC

After replacing with new atmega chip, I'm not able to upload the code

[image]

can anyone help me with this

Thanks !

ps : I'm pretty new to arduino & electronics world :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to share my experience. You can use lots of different bootloaders with serial single sided board but you have to take care of two things:

1. You have to change serial port setting for its speed like if you are using decimila or NG bootloader it should be 19200 bits per sec.
2. Select the correct board type in the Arduino IDE, which will depend on your boot loader.
   You can find this information in the board.txt file, like speed of port, board name and fuse bit settings if you are loading the bootloader in a new, blank chip.

Hope this will solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your board, but I think it shouldn't be a problem. You need to burn the arduino bootloader, before the AVR can be used as an arduino. There's an instructable at http://www.instructables.com/id/Turn-Your-Arduino-Into-an-ISP/step4/Using-Your-Arduino-ISP-Burning-Bootloaders/ how to burn the bootloader through an arduino to an AVR on the breadboard.

An other option would be to use an external programmer - I've got one from pollin for about 15€. You didn't need a bootloader then and could just upload the compiled .hex via AVRDude.

Comment: Sorry, i missed that. Maybe your board isn't compatible with the duemilanove?

Comment: If you have an 16MHZ oscillator (maybe you'll find one on some electronic waste) and 2 22pF capacitors, you could program the 328 with the method above. If you dont need much or precise timing, you could even use the internal 8MHZ oscillator. at http://code.google.com/p/arduino-tiny/source/browse/trunk/hardware/tiny/boards.txt you find a boards.txt that you can use to compile arduino code for a variety of AVR's with or without external oscillator.